# Database design of source control applications

Tags: t-sql, database-design

So I may be in the process of creating an in house source control web application. I'm unsure as to how I should approach the database design. Should the code files be stored in the file system and reference those files in the database? Or should I store the files in the database itself?

Edit: the reason I "may" be on this project is because we may not be able to get an already established source control application on our closed network.

Comment: just use Git!....Why re-invent the wheel? (with a good chance it will be square...)

Comment: I forgot to mention we don't have git on our approved software list on our network, and it may be a greater hassle going through that process than just developing something ourselves.

Comment: "we don't have git on our approved software list on our network" - So,....get it approved!

Comment: We're currently trying to do just that, but I may have to develop something in house if the process takest too long.

Comment: I would start by defining a new language for the source control system. Or do you already have one?

Comment: There are plenty of source control solutions, some are free. I'm sure you can manage some of them to work just by opening a couple of ports in you hermetic intranet. Also those solutions are a lot sophisticated and you ill end with problems those tools solved decades ago.

Comment: Source control doesn't usually use a SQL database on the back end. If I were in your shoes, I'd start by reading about the source control design, and by reading the source code for open sourced systems like RCS, git, and mercurial.